# View Azure SQL User Properties

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In an On-Premises SQL environment I am able to view the User Properties for a SQL User, including User Mapping, but am unable to do so in Azure SQL. How can I view the properties of a SQL User created in Azure SQL? I attempted various SQL Queries, but many of them failed as they were looking for stored procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT pr.principal_id, pr.name, pr.type_desc, 
    pr.authentication_type_desc, pe.state_desc, pe.permission_name
FROM sys.database_principals AS pr
JOIN sys.database_permissions AS pe
    ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id;
```

Those system views involved in this query have more fields/columns you can explore.

Comment: This works on providing some information on users in a database but I need to get the User Mapping for a SQL User. Any ideas on how to execute that?

Comment: Run select on master for sys.sql_logins. Run select sys.database_principals on each database and find matching SIDs